# Count API Requests to external API with Laravel

Tags: laravel, api, limit, external, rate

I've been trying to solve a problem with external service that has a rate limiter. My Laravel app will be doing regular requests via jobs. Users also can interact with the external service. This means that jobs requests + users requests can easily exceed the rate limit of the service and result in a X minute timeout(ban). To prevent that, Laravel app has to know the number of request for the last X minutes/seconds to allow certain method to be executed without exceeding the API rate.
Has anyone ran into the same problem and how did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Probably a solution would be to use a table to store the number of requests for every url (or service provider) with the reset time. When you want to make a query you can refer to the static Eloquent Model to retrieve the number of requests to the url and check of you did not reach the maximum. Also, you can use a service or task to reset the timer on this specific table when the reset time is reached.

Does it help you ?

Comment: try to answer with a sample code maybe.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to count outcomes API requests you can set **event** and **listener** that populate something like `requests` table in DB.

So, register *event* and *listener* in `EventServiceProvider`:

```
protected $listen = [
    'App\Events\RequestSent' => [
        'App\Listeners\IncrementCounterIntoRequestsDBTable',
    ],
];
```

and then: `php artisan event:generate`
[see documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/events#registering-events-and-listeners)

In this scenario, each request dispatch an `event` that increments a counter inside a `requests` table.

*******************************************************************

But if you want to solve the problem of 3rd party API rate limits:

**Optimize** and make something like a **cache**: if you don't need "strict" realtime you can:

- schedules API requests each XX minutes, via commands or further jobs
- store fresh data into your ***internal*** DB
- then you can serves this data to user requests.

In this manner you can have a "pre-defined" update each XX minutes, depending on rate limits.

For example, if you have rate limit about 1.500 req/day you can potentially update your data each minute.

Answer (score -1):

For this type of scenario, you can create a custom middleware for handling different types of requests.

1. Create a middleware by command => `php artisan make:middleware requestCountMiddleware`
2. For new log table you can create a migration and model of `RequestLog::class`  with columns of `id (autoincrement) , count(big integer), timestamps()`.
3. After that inside `App/Http/Middleware/requestCountMiddleware.php` create logic for storing or updating the entry of each request based on the date inside the RequestLog table.

**4. Sample logic as per your request =>**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $checkRequest = App\Models\RequestLog::whereDate('created_at', Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d'))->first();
    if(!$checkRequest){
        $checkRequest = new App\Models\RequestLog();
    }
    $checkRequest->count += 1;
    $checkRequest->save();
    return $next($request);
}
```

5. Also from Job methods you can do the same logic for adding or updating the count of requests.

**6. So whenever you need a count by the date you can get it from that table with this type query =>**
**$date = Any Date what you want data from table ( 2022-09-27 )**

`App\Models\RequestLog::whereDate('created_at', $date)->value('count');`

**7. Use this middleware in the user request route by =>**

```
Route::get('/details', function () {
    //
})->middleware('requestCountMiddleware');
```

Also if you want to handle multiple requests like more than 60 or 120 request per minute than also you can set RateLimiter for handle maximum number of request accept per IP or per user in Laravel app.

Comment: For this type of scenario, it's the opposite: rate-limited endpoint belongs to 3rd party application. Our made Middlewares only track income requests.

Comment: Yes but here I think 3rd party requests are calling inside Laravel as per the question asked. So it is easy for Laravel to track that request.

Comment: Yes of course, you can simply track/log requests, but if quota exceeds, users are bounced. It needs optimize and re-thinking the entire process with a something like a cache solution.

Comment: No I think you have some misunderstanding. Right now here the problem is for track 3rd party request only. And you are saying about local requests. For handling multiple request per minute we also can set RateLimiter with increase number of request per minute.

Comment: Yes I think @NIKUNJKOTHIYA is right with this solution for this problem.

Comment: Yes I agree, we could also dispatch an *event* to track each *outcome* request sent  *to* 3rd party application.

But in my opinion  :-)  it needs to re-think the process (using something like a cache) to solve rate-limit problem of the API calls.